# C# Escritorio : Como Obtengo el icono del cursor actual?

Tags: c#, cursor, icons

### Obtener el cursor actual

Tengo un formulario en el cual cambio de icono al cursor para agregar un determinado icono a un TableLayoutPanel, pero no encuentro una forma en la cual yo pueda obtener el icono que actualmente tiene el cursor, estuve revisando las propiedades de la clase Cursor en C# y existe la Propiedad Cursor.Current que devuelve un objeto que representa al cursor actual la propiedad Cursor.Handle que obtiene el identificador del cursor, encontré un ejemplo en el cual dibuja el icono en el formulario, pero no me otorga el control sobre dicho icono para poder agregarlo donde necesite

Este es mi ejemplo, en el cual quiero obtener el cursor para luego agregarlo dentro de otro control(TableLayoutPanel u otro) y no solo dibujarlo directamente en el formulario:
[image: Cambio dinámico de cursor y la superficie donde quiero agregar]

**ASÍ CAMBIO DE ICONO EN EL MENÚ**
Donde el evento clic sucede sobre un botón de un control personalizado en forma de menú que se despliega al hacer clic sobre el botón agregar, ahí al seleccionar cualquier icono, el cursor toma su forma y es ahí donde yo quiero obtener ese icono y pegarlo en el TableLayoutPanel.

```
private void pb_individuos_click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Icon icono_individuo = Properties.Resources.individuo32;
    ParentForm.Cursor = new Cursor(icono_individuo.Handle);
}
```

**INVESTIGUE Y ENCONTRE UN METODO, PERO SOLO LO DIBUJAN Y NO LO OBTIENEN**
metodo void *Cursor.Draw(**Graphics** g, **Rectangle** targetRect)* donde **Graphics** es la superficie donde se va a dibujar y **Rectangle** son los limites:

```
    private void DrawCursorsOnForm( Cursor cursor )
    {
        if ( this.Cursor != Cursors.Hand & 
        Cursor.Current == Cursors.Default)
        {
            // Draw the cursor stretched.
            Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
              new Point( 10, 10 ), new Size( cursor.Size.Width * 2,
              cursor.Size.Height * 2 ) );
            cursor.DrawStretched( graphics, rectangle );

            // Draw the cursor in normal size.
            rectangle.Location = new Point(
            rectangle.Width + rectangle.Location.X,
              rectangle.Height + rectangle.Location.Y );
            rectangle.Size = cursor.Size;
            cursor.Draw( graphics, rectangle );

            // Dispose of the cursor.
            cursor.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Resultado del ejemplo:
[image: Cursor Dibujado en el formulario]

**OTRO EJEMPLO INVESTIGADO**
En este enlace realizan algo parecido en C# en aplicaciones WPF: [C# get current cursor icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246980/c-sharp-get-current-cursor-icon)

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema. Si con `Cursor.Draw` puedes obtener el bitmap del cursor, cual es el problema a continuación?

Comment: @Pikoh Bueno, mi problema se enfoca en la obtención del icono para poder agregarlo a cualquier control como icono dentro de cualquier control que se necesite en el momento, en el caso expuesto necesito obtener el icono del cursor como puedes ver en el gif al final, al elegir un icono del menu cambia de apariencia el cursor y yo necesito obtener ese icono para agregarlo al TableLayoutPanel, mi problema no radica con `Cursor.Draw`, ese fue un ejemplo que investigue pero lo hace con WPF y lo que hice fue demostrar el ejemplo en la pregunta

Comment: @Pikoh ya hice ediciones en la pregunta, dividí el problema arriba y las investigaciones por mi cuenta abajo, mi objetivo es encontrar un método para obtener el ícono del cursor

Comment: No termino de comprender el problema. Si ya sabes cual es el dibujo que necesitas cuando se lo asignas al cursor, para que fijarte cual es el icono que tiene el cursor?

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista, entonces mi duda se enfoca en que si existe un método que me permita obtener ese ícono o información de el, para mandar a llamar el dibujo correspondiente y no usar variables globales para indicar cual icono seleccionó que sería el método más fácil de lograrlo

Comment: Si solo es eso, cuando cargues determinado icono puedes almacenar su nombre en la propiedad `Tag` del cursor, y después consultarla cuando necesites `Cursor.Tag="Cursor1";`